# How to handle empty post (upto 20 post) without using empty() and "&&" operator

Tags: php

I am receiving post values. I want a suggestion for logic to handle empty or not set post values.

Is there such a way if one of them receives empty post, the $Data array should not receive anymore values and make it empty. In other words, i am trying to immitate the try and catch feature. If on any POST is empty, ignore reading the rest of POST and make that array as empty

Is my second draft considred valid?

**First draft**

```
    if(!empty(isset($_POST["SHOWSCHEDULE_SHOWTYPE"]))){
        $DATA["SHOWSCHEDULE_SHOWTYPE"] = $_POST["SHOWSCHEDULE_SHOWTYPE"];
    }

    if(!empty(isset($_POST["SHOWSCHEDULE_SHOWTITLE"]))){
        $DATA["SHOWSCHEDULE_SHOWTITLE"] = $_POST["SHOWSCHEDULE_SHOWTITLE"];
    }

    if(empty($DATA)){
        //do something
    }else{
        //do something else
    }
```

**Second draft**

```
try{

        if(!empty(isset($_POST["SHOWSCHEDULE_SHOWTITLE"]))){
            $DATA["SHOWTITLE"] = $_POST["SHOWSCHEDULE_SHOWTITLE"];
        }else{
            throw new Exception('POST SHOWSCHEDULE_SHOWTITLE');
        }

        if(!empty(isset($_POST["SHOWSCHEDULE_SHOWTYPE"]))){
            $DATA["SHOWTYPE"] = $_POST["SHOWSCHEDULE_SHOWTYPE"];
        }else{
            throw new Exception('POST SHOWSCHEDULE_SHOWTYPE');
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        unset($DATA);
    }
```

Comment: @Progrock I have updated my code. Perhaps this gives a clearer picture. Is 2nd draft valid?

Comment: [*"but its gets very long with 20 post values"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54210280/how-to-handle-empty-post-without-using-empty-and-operator#comment95247395_54210332). That should have originally been part of the question (edit: and not just in the edited title). I don't see "20" in your question, I see one `$_POST["SHOWSCHEDULE_SHOWTITLE"]`.

Comment: Why downvote? I think i had a reasonable question.

Comment: What do you mean by empty?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one `if` statement with all required POST parameters.

```
if(!empty($_POST['var1']) && !empty($_POST['var2']) && !empty($_POST['var3']) && !empty($_POST['var4'])):
/*and then assign all the POST values to a $DATA array as you want.*/
$DATA['var1'] = $_POST['var1'];
$DATA['var2'] = $_POST['var2'];/* and so on..*/
endif;
```

Comment: Yes, I did use that method earlier, but its gets very long with 20 post values. So i wanted to use my method but similar concept like yours

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to white list values that I loop through and assign.

```
<?php

$valid_keys = ['SHOWSCHEDULE_SHOWTYPE', 'SHOWSCHEDULE_SHOWTITLE'];

$at_least_one_empty = false;
foreach($valid_keys as $data_key)
{
    $data[$data_key] = isset($_POST[$data_key])
        ? trim($_POST[$data_key]) // Remove accidental user whitespace.
        : ''; // If unsubmitted - set to empty string.

    if($data[$data_key] === '')
        $at_least_one_empty = true;
}

if($at_least_one_empty) {
    unset($data);
} else {
    process($data);
}
```

Note with the sample code above an unsubmitted value will be assigned the empty string.  This might not be the behaviour you want.

However if you just want to assign and check you received all inputs this might do (no filtering or validation):

```
<?php
$valid_keys = ['SHOWSCHEDULE_SHOWTYPE', 'SHOWSCHEDULE_SHOWTITLE'];

foreach($valid_keys as $data_key)
    $data[$data_key] = $_POST[$data_key] ?? null;

$not_all_received = in_array(null, $data, true);
```